# What's the purpose of .properties files in APK packages?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, apk, packaging

When analyzing an APK, I've found a whole lot of `.properties` files in the archive's root, indicating the version numbers of Google Play services, Firebase and the Google HTTP client, for example:

```
version=19.2.0
client=firebase-database
firebase-database_client=19.2.0
```

These could theoretically be excluded from the package alike:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude "firebase-*.properties"
        exclude "play-services-*.properties"
        exclude "google-http-client.version"
    }
}
```

However, this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/671) suggests it would be the "intended behavior". So is it safe to exclude these seemingly useless files from the package - or are they required by Google Play, in order to expose these version numbers to automated package-content scans? Is the purpose of these version number files documented somewhere?

---

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image: Analyze APK screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of the documentation, which answers the question, may have not existed back then:

---

Source: [Dependency information for Play Console](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency-info-play):

> When building your app using AGP 4.0.0 and higher, the plugin includes metadata that describes the library dependencies that are compiled into your app. When uploading your app, the Play Console inspects this metadata to provide alerts for known issues with SDKs and dependencies your app uses, and, in some cases, provide actionable feedback to resolve those issues.

> The data is compressed, encrypted by a Google Play signing key, and stored in the signing block of your release app. We recommend keeping this dependencies file for a safe and positive user experience. However, if you’d rather not share this information, you can opt out by including the following `dependenciesInfo` block in your module’s `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    dependenciesInfo {

        // Disables dependency metadata when building APKs.
        includeInApk = false

        // Disables dependency metadata when building Android App Bundles.
        includeInBundle = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, the `.properties` file stores key-value parameters can be read inside the library or from the code outside. Just as an example, let's take the `play-service-ads-identifier` library:

[image: play-service-ads-identifier structure]

The properties file is copied from `aar` base dir to `apk` root directory. This is how the build system works. I investigate inside this library and I didn't find any reference to the properties contained in the file `play-services-ads-identifier.properties`. I think it's a common situation for all the remaining library that you use. I suppose the only use of those files is to fast detect which library version is used by the apps.

Moreover I found this note from [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

> Note: ProGuard directives are included in the Play services client libraries to preserve the required classes. The Android Plugin for Gradle automatically appends ProGuard configuration files in an AAR (Android ARchive) package and appends that package to your ProGuard configuration. During project creation, Android Studio automatically creates the ProGuard configuration files and build.gradle properties for ProGuard use. To use ProGuard with Android Studio, you must enable the ProGuard setting in your build.gradle buildTypes. For more information, see the ProGuard guide.

As you can read, the Android Plugin for Gradle adds whatever it needs to package the apk, proguard configuration included. If the properties are not removed I think it is a choice. I don't know if they allow the system a faster apk inspection. I looked for more documentation about it and I didn't find anything about those properties file. **If they are used by Play Service, it is no documented**. Honestly, in my project I just leave those file, they do not affect apk size in a significant way. Considering that the size of these files is minimal, **I suggest you leave them where they are**.

Comment: Explaining where these files actually come from is at least worth +1, while I'd basically need to know if they are essential for Google Play. Think that I've once read that they require one to build against the lastest libraries, which is the reason for my suspicion. Most libraries do not have these version number files, only the Google & Firebase ones have them - and Android by itself does not require them, therefore it is unclear if this is packaged clutter or something of importance.

Comment: I look for more documentation about it and I didn't find anything about those properties file. Probably you are right, these files are useless. If they are used by Play Service it no documented. Honestly, in my project I just leave those file, they do not affect apk size in a significant way.

Comment: Well, I'd know who to ask at Google, but I cannot tag in people as in any other social network... your attempt at an answer rather raised a new one question: which purpose these files have inside AAR files? And I'm not really bothered by their size, but about the cluttered directory index. When these version number files only have purpose in the AAR files, they're probably useless in APK files.

Comment: They might be used by Play Console to analyze the APK and libraries it uses. I've recently excluded those properties files from the APK and later received a warning that the app was not using latest version.

Comment: I've just found the official documentation by chance ...and added it as canonical answer.

Answer (score -5):

.properties files mainly used in Java related technologies to store the configurable parameters of an application. 
They can also be used for storing strings for Internationalization and localization.
It stores data in form of Key-Value Parameter.

In case of Firebase It Stores user Analytics related information read more here [enter link description here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486)